# How to setup and use the firebase v9 into class based react project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am new in react. How can I use firebase inside react project.

//  config file of firebase looks like this
//../src/firebase.js

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCXaeZcvAMHJPKnWNob6iJrfSNakCFfoew",
    authDomain: "cart-items-72efc.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "cart-items-72efc",
    storageBucket: "cart-items-72efc.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "38214317083",
    appId: "1:38214317083:web:cca4fc6829824dae1a74be"
};
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
```

// Want to use db inside app.js which is class based component
//../src/components/app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import db from '../firebase';
import {collection} from 'firebase/firestore';

class App extends Component{
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            products: [],
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        db.collection('item').onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
           const products = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
               const data = doc.data();
               data['id'] = doc.id;
               return data;
          });
         this.setState({
             products:products
         })
       })
      }
    }
```

I do this kind of setup but not able to get data from firebase and get some compilation error.

Thank you for any help:)

Comment: The Firebase documentation has side-by-side example of the v8 and v9 SDKs, and this one should be covered here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#web-version-9_1.

Comment: `import { db } from "../firebase"` (the `{}`) as there is no default export.

Comment: I did this but it give me initializeApp is not a fuction. If you have some time than please, give us a  working setup of above code.
It's great help.